# MySql transaction works only in console

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mariadb

When i paste this into MySql console

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `orders` (customer_id) VALUES ('2');
SET @lastid=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `transactions`
    (order_id,product_id,product_quantity,price,ammount,customer_id)
    VALUES (@lastid,'3','2','4','4','2');
INSERT INTO `transactions`
    (order_id,product_id,product_quantity,price,ammount,customer_id)
    VALUES (@lastid,'1','3','5','4','2');
COMMIT;
```

it works fine, when i try to do the same via php

```
$sql = "START TRANSACTION;";
$sql .="INSERT INTO `orders` (customer_id) VALUES ('$customer_id_form');";
$sql .="SET @lastid=LAST_INSERT_ID();";
foreach ($product_id_form as $key => $product){
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `transactions`
    (order_id,product_id,product_quantity,price,ammount,customer_id) 
    VALUES 
    (@lastid,'$product','$quantity_form[$key]',
        '$price_form[$key]','$amount_form[$key]','$customer_id_form');";
}
$sql .= "COMMIT;";
//$sql = "INSERT INTO products (`product_name`,`curent_price`,`product_quota`) VALUES ('$productname_form','$productprice_form','$productquote_form')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
   header("Location: order.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

it does not work error shown is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `orders` (customer_id) VALUES ('2');SET
>   @lastid=LAST_INSERT_ID();INS' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Perform the queries one at a time; do not try to send them all at once to the server.  The `START`...`COMMIT` will determine the transactional semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need  [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), to execute multiple queries